# Python function calling

Tags: python

I've only started learning Python. If I wrote:

```
def questions(): 
    sentence= input(" please enter a sentence").split()
```

How would I end the function If the user didn't input anything and just hit enter

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: The function will end on its own since it is complete after any user input. `if sentence == []: print('No user input detected')` is something you may be looking for, though.

Comment: You could add a `return` statement if `len(sentence) == 0`

Comment: Which version of Python? 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

```
def questions():
    sentence= input(" please enter a sentence").split()
    if sentence == []:
        #This is what happens when nothing was entered
    else:
        #This happens when something was entered
```

Comment: You could shorten it to `if sentence:`

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to make it clear that .split() returns a list and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Did you test this? The function will work properly if the user simply hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `sentence` variable would be an empty list. If there was nothing else in the function, it would return `None`, the default return value. If you wanted to do further processing that requires an actual sentence with content, you can put `if not sentence: return` after that line.

Comment: This fails with `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` in Python 2 btw unless they use `raw_input`

Comment: @roganjosh - That's fine; nobody uses `input` in Python 2 anyway, and they shouldn't be using Python 2 in the first place. :P I answer based on the current standard, which is Python 3, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Um, I've ended up being stuck in Python 2 so my instinct is to answer along that vein :P But also, many tutorials will work with Python 2 so for beginner questions I would definitely anticipate such things!

Answer (score 0):

You can add exception in your code.
If you want to raise an exception only on the empty string, you'll need to do that manually:

Example

```
 try:
    input = raw_input('input: ')
    if int(input):
        ......
except ValueError:
    if not input:
        raise ValueError('empty string')
    else:
        raise ValueError('not int')
```

try this, both empty string and non-int can be detected.

Comment: OP is using python3 :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm How do you know that? I didn't get a response to my question.